# How to get value Check and Uncheck checkbox use JQuery on array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

Now im doing PHP Project combine with JQuery. I want to get value from checkbox both checked and unchecked on array. here is what i try

```
$(function() {
      $('.dealprice').on('input', function(){

        if($('.dealprice:checkbox:checked').prop('checked')){
            //CHECKED
            console.log("Checked");
            const getPrice = $(this).closest("tr").find('input[name=itemprice]').val();
            console.log(getPrice);
        }else{
            //UNCHECKED
            console.log("Uncheck");
            const getPrice = $(this).closest("tr").find('input[name=itemprice]').val();
            console.log(getPrice); 
        }
        
    });
 });
```

i make a sample on this site. https://repl.it/@ferdinandgush/get-value-checkbox please click "RUN" bottom on the top to able test it.

the problem is, when the checkbox checked more then 1 and when i want to uncheck 1 of it. it still return value "True" not "false".

what i want it. each of checkbox can return value wherever i checked and uncheck it.

checked return `consolo.log('true');`

unchecked return `consolo.log('false');`

please help

Comment: Are you still having problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can just do it like this `if ($(this).prop('checked')) {`

Then it will only check if the checkbox that you click on is checked or not.

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.dealprice').on('input', function() {

    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      //CHECKED
      console.log("Checked");
      const getPrice = $(this).closest("tr").find('input[name=itemprice]').val();
      console.log(getPrice);
    } else {
      //UNCHECKED
      console.log("Uncheck");
      const getPrice = $(this).closest("tr").find('input[name=itemprice]').val();
      console.log(getPrice);
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-qh0q{background-color:#c0c0c0;color:#000000;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-0lax{text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-amwm{font-weight:bold;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tg">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-qh0q">Item</th>
      <th class="tg-qh0q">Price</th>
      <th class="tg-qh0q">Deal</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0lax">Book</td>
      <td class="tg-0lax">$ 10 <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="10"></td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"><input type="checkbox" class="dealprice" name="deal[12][0]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0lax">Pencil</td>
      <td class="tg-0lax">$ 5 <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="5"></td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"><input type="checkbox" class="dealprice" name="deal[12][1]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0lax">Pen</td>
      <td class="tg-0lax">$ 8 <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="8"></td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"><input type="checkbox" class="dealprice" name="deal[12][2]"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0lax">spidol</td>
      <td class="tg-0lax">$ 15 <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="15"></td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"><input type="checkbox" class="dealprice" name="deal[12][3]"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @ferdinand No problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".dealprice").change(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                console.log(true);
            } else {
                console.log(false);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: While this may answer the problem, it's always a good idea to leave a comment about why this solves the OP's problem

Comment: Basically we are adding a change event on all of the checkbox. So,  whenever the checkbox's checked/unchecked, the function attached to the change event gets triggered.